# Error : list index out of range for a fourier sum code

Tags: python, list, indexing, range

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate #imports quad
from scipy.signal import square
from scipy.signal import sawtooth
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L=np.pi
x = np.linspace(-L,L,1000)
f = sawtooth(x,width=0.5)
n = []
for j in range(2,11,1):
    x = 1.0*j
    j = j+1
    x = int(x) 
    n.append(x)
print(n)
an = np.zeros(n) 
bn = np.zeros(n)
li = -L 
lf = L
L1 = (lf-li)/2
a0 = (1.0/L1)*integrate.quad(lambda x : sawtooth(x,width=0.5),li,lf)[0]

for i in range(1,n[x]+1):
    an[i-1]= (1.0/L1)*integrate.quad(lambda x: sawtooth(x,width=0.5)*np.cos(i*np.pi*x/L1),li,lf)[0]
    bn[i-1]= (1.0/L1)*integrate.quad(lambda x: sawtooth(x,width=0.5)*np.sin(i*np.pi*x/L1),li,lf)[0]
print(an[i-1],bn[i-1])
a1=np.array(an)
print("Fourier coefficient A_n =",a1)
b1=np.array(bn)
print("Fourier coefficient B_n =",b1)
s = a0*0.5 + sum([a1[k-1]*np.cos(k*np.pi*x/L1)+b1[k-1]*np.sin(k*np.pi*x/L1) for k in range (1,n+1)])
plt.plot(x,s,x,sawtooth(x,width=0.5))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File 

     "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

      File "c:\users\dell\n=2to10trianglewave-pitopi.py", line 32, in <module>
for i in range(1,n[x]+1):

    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I need the fourier coefficients for n = 2 to 10 values, I did the for loop for the value of n but then in the next for loop I get the error "list index is out of range". I can't understand where I'm violating the index range. Please tell me how to correct it.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: What is the range of numbers you are trying to iterate over with `for i in range(1,n[x]+1):` ?

Comment: @Tzane i am trying to iterate over the values 2 to 10

Comment: What's up with that `n` list creation? Why not go straight for `n = np.arange(2, 11)`? And why use a bunch of lambdas when you could just pass `f` to the integrator function?

Answer (score -1):

You're getting the error at this line in your code:

```py
for i in range(1,n[x]+1)
```

and it's because if you check the value of both `n` and `x`

```py
>> print(n)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>> print(x)
10

>> n[x]
Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

you see, `n` is a list of lengths 9 (having values from index 0 to 8) and when you do `n[x]`, it throws `IndexError` as clearly it doesn't have the index `10`

Comment: can you please tell me how I can correct it?

Comment: how many times do you wish to iterate over using this loop or what's the meaning of this iteration?

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of things that are wrong in your initial code:

- `L = pi` is confusing. `li = -L`, `lf = L`, `L1 = (lf-li)/2` are even more confusing. You need to write down the period of your signal as a constant.
- The creation of the `n` list does not help. Define how many terms of the Fourier series you want as a constant.
- `lambda x: sawtooth(x, width=0.5)` appears too many times. Define a function to create your original signal and reuse that function in the integrals.
- Same problem with `integrate.quad(... *np.cos(i*np.pi*x/L1), li, lf)[0]`. Define a helper function to perform the integrals since everything is always the same: the signal function, the integration boundaries, etc. The only thing that changes is the trigonometric function being a cosine or a sine.

Below is the result after fixing those problems. I went with a square signal as it shows the Fourier series more clearly than a sawtooth signal.

[image]

```py
# Imports.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.signal import square

# Constants.
PI = np.pi
BOUNDARIES = (-4*PI, +4*PI)
SERIES_TERMS: int = 10
DUTY: float = 0.7
PERIOD = 2*PI # Because that's how the scipy.signal waveforms are defined.

# Helper function.
def integral(function):
    return 2/PERIOD * quad(function, -PERIOD/2, +PERIOD/2)[0]

def series_term(function, trig_function, i: int):
    return integral(lambda x, i=i: function(x)*trig_function(i*x))

# Data.
f = lambda x: square(x, DUTY)
x = np.linspace(*BOUNDARIES, 1000)
y = f(x) # Original signal.

# Calculate the cosine and sine terms of the Fourier series.
an = np.zeros(SERIES_TERMS)
bn = np.zeros(SERIES_TERMS)

an[0] = integral(f)/2
bn[0] = 0
for i in range(1, SERIES_TERMS):
    an[i] = series_term(f, np.cos, i)
    bn[i] = series_term(f, np.sin, i)

# Sum the terms to get the approximated signal.
s = an[0] + sum([an[i]*np.cos(i*x) + bn[i]*np.sin(i*x) for i in range(1, SERIES_TERMS)])

# Plot the signal and its approximation.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
ax.plot(x, y, label="Original signal")
ax.plot(x, s, label=f"Fourier series ({SERIES_TERMS})")
ax.legend(loc="lower right", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
ax.grid()
fig.show()
```

The only thing left to do is to optimize the sum operation. There must be a way to use broadcasting and a fancy dot product there.